# Ubuntu reboot freeze

Tags: ubuntu, operating-systems, bootloader, systemd

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 host.

But when I tried to boot it, it said default.target not found.

And I tried to enter rescue mode and emergency mode, both of them failed.

Please help me.

```
system [1]: Unit default.target not found
system [1]: Falling back to rescue.target.
system [1]: Unit rescue.target not found.
Failed to load rescue.target
system [1]: Freezing execution.
```

Comment: Check and repair the SSD or HHD  by running Ubuntu from USB drive and use Disks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is happening due to the missing [default.target] file and the [rescue.target] from the directory:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/
```

Try to copy those 2 files from another machine and place them under the directory, then make sure that the [default.target] is a symbolic link to the [graphical.target].

```
sudo ll /usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target
 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 21 12:54 /usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target -> graphical.target
```

The content of the [graphical.target] should have the following:

```
sudo cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target

    [Unit]
    Description=Graphical Interface
    Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
    Requires=multi-user.target
    Wants=display-manager.service
    Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
    After=multi-user.target rescue.service rescue.target display-manager.service
    AllowIsolate=yes
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but these files shouldn't just disappear for no reason - probably some critical package is missing along with a number of other essential files and there must be a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Make ubuntu<your_ubuntu_version> live usb

boot using live usb then choose "Try ubuntu"

"search the missing file path on internet"

Open folder in ubuntu and go to " + other locations "

copy missing files from usb to your ubuntu drive

if ask permission to copy then use " sudo -H nautilus " in terminal. A new

folder is open with root access...use this folder to copy-paste.

""""""""""""""""""""""""reboot"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

follow same for other missing files.....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).